# Install Once For Two Operating Systems?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I got 1 laptop with single tiny 120GB ssd drive

I need two setups

win7 32bit professional with visual studio 2010 and office 2007 - in the companies domain

NOTICE: i must have it NOT on a VM.

win7 64bit ultimate with visual studio 2010 and office 2007 - out of companies domain

is there any way I can install visual studio and office in a way they won't take room twice?

Comment: why is a VM not an option?

Comment: Microsoft does warn against installing the same product for two OSes, on the same location of the drive. You can try and it may even work, but you won't be supported. If you manually set the location during installation, I can't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: buy a bigger SSD. the cheapest and easiest solution.

Comment: @akira I work with unique hardware. I don't want to take the risks involving the diffrences between real and simulated. as the final station is unsimulated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? Else I would close this question as being too localized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put in the 32-bit one in a virtual machine, install and use vs and office only on the 64-bit os running directly on the hardware.

For your second question, you can have local users. The computer is still part of the domain.

Comment: impossible, I do devolopment for external hardware that has only 32bit drivers. also the 32 bit system must be in the domain.

Comment: @fsxt 
will my local user be limited by the domain? I need full access to my computer from the local user anywhere.

Comment: I think VMWare does USB pass-trough, so if your devices are USB you might still be able to use 32-bit drivers installed in the VM.

Comment: Your local user will have the access you give it. If you make it a member of the local administrators group you will have full access to the local computer.

Comment: Also, you can make the VM a domain member.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only option that i can think of, and it probably won't work.  If you have a few days to burn, you can try it.  In general I would say this isn't possible, especially because of the fact that you are running two different bits ;)

Make 3 partitions

1. Win 7 32
2. Win 7 64
3. Applications

Install the OS's as normal, and then install all applications on partition #3, into the same directories, and see if anything breaks.  Maybe you will get lucky, but I doubt it.

Options for the VM (VM is 32bit, host is 64 bit)

1. Do dev on the host machine, but debug in the 32bit using VS remote debugging, if possible for what you are writing.  If it's drivers, i'm guessing you'll just be staring at minidumps
2. Install VS in the VM, and then use vmware's 'app sharing' thing to make it look like you are working on the 64 bit site.  Same goes for office.

Even better would be to [invest $100 and buy a 500GB drive](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136856).  I've bought more expensive things just to make my work life better, even though I dont' get reimbursed for them.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Visual Studio forcing you to install most of its contents on the System partition, I think (assumption, not sure) that Visual Studio installed on x86 and x64 are not quite compatible and might lead to problems. There are either apps that are not installed in the registry which can easily be placed on a third partition, or apps that don't necessarily need the registry entries to work, which can also be installed on a third partition.

To follow what the others said, to make it all easier and WAY less problematic I would just buy a bigger hard drive, either a non-SSD which would be quite cheap, or a 256GB SSD, which doesn't cost the world either.